# I have a weird error for a list in unity I'm trying to use, and I just couldn't find an answer for it

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm quite new to unity and recently this weird error came up. I've searched the internet for an answer for a while now, so I decided I should ask for help here.

The error is:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'List1' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface. UnityEngine.Component.GetComponentList1(at C:/buildslabe/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/ComponentBindings.gen.cs:48)".

I'm trying to store some game objects in the list, so the camera can change between objects to follow.

This is the part of my code where the list appears:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private List<GameObject> targetList = new List<GameObject>();

private void Start()
{
    targetList = GetComponent<List<GameObject>>();
}
```

Comment: I believe this is because you cannot use the default Serializer to serialize Unity GameObjects - think there are 3rd party apps out there to accomplish this however.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to store in `targetList`? Are they GameObjects that are parented underneath the CameraController object? Where are they relative to the CameraController in the scene? If they're not hierarchically organized, do they have a unique tag or other identifying feature? This information is important, since otherwise you don't have a way to get references to them to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly..
This line into your Start method is unnecessary:

`targetList = GetComponent<List<GameObject>>();`

You just need to Drag and Drop the script 'CameraController' into your camera and then your list of GameObjects will be appearing in the inspector of Camera, so you can just drag and drop the Objects to this List.

Something like this:

[image: camera-targets]